# Microsoft Loop can't save workspace (InternalServerError)

Tags: microsoft-office, office365

Whenever i login to Microsoft Loop public preview and create a Workspace I get the following message (translated from German):

> The loop workspace and the pages you created could not be saved. They
> will be lost as soon as you refresh or leave this page. Copy and paste
> anything of them that you want to keep to another location. Then try
> to create this workspace again.

Here's a picture of it (in German)

[image: Loop cant save Workspace]

Does anyone know how I can fix this? Can I fix this or is this on Microsofts side? What setup do I need to save Loop Workspaces?

In the Browser Console (Firefox and Edge) I get the following Error Message:

[image: Loop Console]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft releases new functionality for Office365 with [public previews](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-365/public-preview). These aren't finalized applications but under active development, so some features might not be available, others may fail. It's sort of public beta testing that offers users the possibility to provide feedback for MS.

Stated by a MS Loop team member yesterday (March 23 2023):

> Hi folks, thanks for checking out Loop on the first day of Public Preview. Sorry about this issue with the reliability of creating new workspaces. Several engineers on our team are in-progress investigating it, today, and we hope to have a fix out soon.

Source: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/officeinsider/forum/all/problems-getting-started-error-message-on-every/77f6586e-418a-4f3b-9e50-b80337bae63f

Comment: I know errors are expected but could not find any thread about this. We were waiting for loop a long time in my team, hope they fix this soon. Sad sysadmin noises

Comment: Yeah, I figured you would - that part's more for those who don't understand the term "public preview" :-) I actually found that thread by googling with the first sentence in your translated error message. As there's a bunch of postings, I'd expect MS guys to post updates there.

Comment: I re-worded the answer to be a bit more clear for absolute beginners.

Comment: really? if i search with my first sentence I can't find anything :). Funny. Maybe my eyes automatically filter out answers.microsoft pages because normally they are not helpful at all.

Comment: :'D Funny indeed - for me the first hit is your question, the second the MS thread. Go figure.